# hibernate criteria if collection contains collection

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, restriction

I have a Priv class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PK_PRIVS", schema = "dbo")
public class Priv implements java.io.Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String code;
private String name;
private String description;
private PrivType type;
//...
}
```

and a Report class which has many to many relation with Priv and contains Set of associated Privs - privs.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT", schema = "dbo")
public class Report implements java.io.Serializable {

//...

private Set<Priv> privs = new HashSet<Priv>(0);

//...

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "REPORT_PK_PRIVS", schema = "dbo", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PK_PRIVS_CODE") })
public Set<Priv> getPrivs() {
    return this.privs;
}

public void setPrivs(Set<Priv> privs) {
    this.privs = privs;
}



}
```

Now I have a Set of Strings, which are codes of Priv classes (code is Primary Key in Priv).

```
Set<String> privsCodesSet; //set of codes of Priv classes
```

I need a criterion which allow me to find that Reports, which all codes from its Priv set contains in privsCodesSet. For example if I have privsCodeSet = {"code1", "code2"}

Report with privs with codes {"code1"" should be in result, but
Report with privs with codes {"code1", "code2", "code3"} should not.

I also have class which is join of Priv and Report, but I'm not sure if it's help.

Comment: I tried sth like this : Criteria reportPrivCriteria = currentSession().createCriteria(
    Report.class, "r");
  reportPrivCriteria.createCriteria("privs", "p");reportPrivCriteria.add(Resstriction.in(p.code, privsCodeSet))

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
    Criteria reportPrivCriteria = currentSession()
        .createCriteria( Report.class, "r");
    reportPrivCriteria.createAlias("privs", "p");
    reportPrivCriteria.add(Restrictions.in(p.code, privsCodeSet));
```

Do you have something like this on your Priv class?

```
    private Set<Report> reports;

    // ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="privs")
    public Collection<Report> getReports() {
         return reports;
    }
```